# EXTjs ViewConfig rowclass

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

using Extjs I was looking for changing my `background-color` from a row in a grid. So far I have only achive changing one color.

Here is my `ViewConf`

```
viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function (record, index) {
            switch (record.get('status')){
                case 'load': return 'blue-row';break;
                case 'miss': return 'blue-row';break;
                case 'Active': return 'green-row';break;
                default: return 'white-row'; break;
            }
        }
    }
```

in my css file I have:

```
.green-row .x-grid-cell {
background-color: #43CE45 ;
}​
.white-row .x-grid-cell {
background-color: #FFFFFF ;
}​
.blue-row .x-grid-cell {
background: #C4C4C4;
}​
```

Just the first in the css list is painted, the others are ignored. In this case, just the green rows are painted green, the others, although they have the class assigned, they aren´t being painted. If I change the order, just the fist is the one to be paint in the grid.

How can I set multiple colors to the grid rows? all the examples I have seen just use 2 colors the primary and the default.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the classes are being applied? Doesn't really make sense that moving them around would make a difference. Also, those breaks are redundant.

Comment: yes, I checked it on the browser console style tab, they are assigned and change in run time if the row's data is changed. I also checked for overwrite rules in any other part but no.

Comment: I would suggest you post a test case, because the colours get applied that match the classes, see: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1rl5

Comment: The example was usefull in learning but still having the same issue.

Comment: Which is why I suggest you post a test case, I'm not going to guess all the possible reasons why you're having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, its validation with `record.get('status')` is not falling in cases `miss` and `Active`. 

Try debugging your program and check the status by doing this:

```
viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function (record, index) {

            console.log('status => ' + record.get('status'));

            switch (record.get('status')){
                case 'load': return 'blue-row';break;
                case 'miss': return 'blue-row';break;
                case 'Active': return 'green-row';break;
                default: return 'white-row'; break;
            }
        }
    }
```

[See that fiddle case is working](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1n37&view/editor)

Comment: OP said in the comments that the classes are being applied correctly.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I believe the problem here is with status validation! Maybe he will never be `miss` or `Active`

Comment: I already used the `console.log` and checked the class being assigned in the first load and changed in runtime when the status column is modified. Always changes the class to the correct one but still painting just the first in the css

Comment: @Giancarlo Benítez please then provide an example fiddle with the same error.